# zip2john not working in latest windows Openwall distribution

Tags: windows, installation, cmd.exe, zip, bug

I just downloaded *1.9.0-jumbo-1 64-bit Windows binaries* from [openwall.com](https://www.openwall.com/john/). I added everything to the *PATH* and everything was running smoothly, until I tried to run *zip2john.exe* from the *CMD*: the executable does not produce any error, but simply seems to do nothing at all. Even if I try to run something like the following

```
zip2john boxx1.zip > hash.txt
```

the *hash.txt* file comes out empty and no error is signaled. What is going on? If you need further information I will be happy to give it to you.

Answer (score -1):

you need to run next step

```
john hash.txt
```

it will take times, after finish run this command to show the password

```
john hash.txt --show
```

Comment: This is not really answer to the question. Please add further information on how this solves the problem of an empty hash file or your answer will most likely be deleted.